# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que Flask me devuelva el JSON completo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, api, flask

Estuve probando hacer mi primera API con Flask y noté que cuando quiero que me devuelva un dato específico de un JSON, lo hace sin problemas, pero cuando le pido todo el JSON, no me lo devuelve, y me tira error. Probé también con jsonify, pero aún así no logro encontrar la solución.

```
from flask import Flask
import json
import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/hola", methods = ['GET'])
def datos():
    nombre = "db_2023.json"
    archivo = open(nombre, "r")
    datos = json.load(archivo)
    return jsonify(datos)
    
app.run(debug=True)
```

El error que me tira es el siguiente:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Tengo la última versión de Flask, y de Python, tengo la 3.6.2. Capaz es un error boludo, pero me tiene frenado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te genera ese error porque estás intentando importar jsonify como un módulo y no como una función de un módulo. Para solucionar ese problema debes importar jsonify directamente desde flask:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify
```

Comment: Uff me re salvaste, gracias. Además, no sabía la diferencia entre ponerlo como un módulo y ponerlo como una función de un módulo. Espectacular!